# Having issue with query string htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Tried looking via search but I couldn't find a match for this particular issue.

Needing to redirect /games/ps3/?page=2 to /ps3/games/2/. All of the approaches I've tried so far won't remove the query string and grab the page value to pass into my new URL.

A little bit new to these types of redirects as I don't work with them often, so I'm guessing it might be a RedirectRule-type approach but I'm not sure.

(Note that due to how the URLs work with other pages on the site I'm having to create the rule for each platform, i.e. I need have a separate rule for both ps3 and xbox-360. So the only variable here is the page number.)

I was thinking it might work something like

```
RewriteRule ^games/ps3/?page=(.*)$ /ps3/games/$1/? [L,R=301]
```

But I think the first ? is causing the rule to fail since the second part uses it. I tried looking online to see how to resolve that possible issue but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up messing around with the rules and got this to solve the issue:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^games/ps3/$ /ps3/games/%1/? [L,R=301]
```